# How to find string name on array and show all

Tags: c#

when i code for some program
i found error
on section **array.find**
its say **Try the specifying Arguments explicitly**

```
int x;
string[] b = new string[5];
b[0] = "Tukul";
b[1] = "Dedy";
b[2] = "Aldi";
b[3] = "Anang";
b[4] = "Aconk";
Console.WriteLine(b[0] + " " + b[1] + " " + b[2] + " " + b[3] + " " + b[4]);
Console.WriteLine("Masukan Huruf awal yang ingin dicari : ");
string nama = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Nama yang ditemukan !!");
for (x = 0; x < 5; x++)
{
    string apa = Array.FindAll(b[x], element => element.StartsWith(nama, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(10, '='));
    Console.WriteLine(apa);
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(10, '='));
}
```

Comment: There is no Array.Find in your code.  Specify the exact error message you are getting (we don't need the whole stack dump, just the error).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following.  The problem on the original code is on [Array.FindAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kkxfxdd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), as the first argument is an array of T (`string[] b` in your case) and it returns an array of T (`string[]` in your case).

```
int x;

string[] b = new string[5];

b[0] = "Tukul";
b[1] = "Dedy";
b[2] = "Aldi";
b[3] = "Anang";
b[4] = "Aconk";

Console.WriteLine(b[0] + " " + b[1] + " " + b[2] + " " + b[3] + " " + b[4]);
Console.WriteLine("Masukan Huruf awal yang ingin dicari : ");
string nama = Console.ReadLine();
Console.Clear();
Console.WriteLine("Nama yang ditemukan !!");

foreach (var apa in Array.FindAll(b, element => element.StartsWith(nama, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(10, '='));
    Console.WriteLine(apa);
    Console.WriteLine("".PadLeft(10, '='));
}
```

Comment: thx for the answer
prefer wdosanjos code
it's fit on me

Answer (score 2):

`b[x]` is a single string variable.You should pass an `array` as parameter if you want to use `Array.FindAll` method

```
Array.FindAll(b, element => element.StartsWith(nama, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```

That will return a string array.You can't assign it to a string.if you want to check current element then you can use:

```
 string apa = b[x].StartsWith(nama, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```